# What prevents my S3 bucket from being terminated?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am a root user for the account, there are no IAM's Why do I get this message when trying to delete my bucket.

> Insufficient permissions to delete bucket After you or your AWS admin
> have updated your IAM permissions to allow s3:DeleteBucket, choose
> delete bucket. Learn more about Identity and Access Management in
> Amazon S3 API response Access Denied

How do I as the root user remove this bucket?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is probably a bucket policy defined for your bucket that is denying the `s3:DeleteBucket` permission on all principals. You must delete the bucket policy in order to be able to delete it. A similar question was asked here:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=815481

At the end of the thread, an AWS user provides the following steps to resolve the problem:

> The reason why you are receiving 'Access Denied' error message while
> deleting the S3 bucket in spite trying via Root account is mostly due
> to the presence of a Deny effect on 's3:DeleteBucket' action for all
> Principals. This denies all AWS identities from performing
> 's3:DeleteBucket' action on the S3 bucket.
>
> However, a Root user can go ahead delete the S3 bucket policy even if
> there is a strict deny policy. In order to gain access back to the
> bucket, I would request you to follow the below process:
>
> 1. Login as Root user(not as an IAM Admin user) in AWS Console.
> 2. Navigate to S3 Console.
> 3. Select the bucket that you have lost access
>    to. You will get an "Access Denied" error message. Ignore the the
>    error message and click on the 'Permissions' tab.
> 4. Next click on 'Bucket Policy' tab and choose 'Delete'.
>
> After deleting the bucket policy, refresh the page and you will gain
> access to the bucket. Now you can go ahead and delete the bucket.